# How to apply JsonExtensionData (Dictionary<string, JToken>) to another object with JSON.Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I came across this (seemingly usual) scenario but I could not find a satisfying solution. Maybe someone knows:

For some reason I parse JSON and I allow the user to provide more key-value pairs than my class has properties. I store the arbitrary ones away like so:

```
class MusterNode
{
    // some definite property
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    // takes the rest
    // see https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeExtensionData.htm
    [JsonExtensionData]
    private Dictionary<string, JToken> _extparams;
}
```

If I deserialize something like

```
{
   "TypeName": "a",
   "stuff": 3
}
```

TypeName will be set and my _extparams contains a key "stuff".

For some reason I want to apply that stored data to another (just created) object 'obj' (in fact the parameters were thought for that typename thingy).
So I have a Dictionary and an object. Is there a way to 'apply' the dictionary without serializing it first?

My non-satisfying solution is this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_extparams);
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, obj);
```

decorated with some JsonSerializerSettings, this works for me. But it does unnecessary work.

Comment: whats the type of your `obj`?

Comment: For the question it is not important. Just imagine the serialized key value pairs match the properties and type of the object (by intelligentce)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Json.Net does not have a method which will populate an object directly from a standard dictionary.  After all, it is a serialization library, not a mapping library.  That said, there is a way to make it work without the intermediate serialization/deserialization step.

First, instead of using a `Dictionary<string, JToken>` as the container for your `[JsonExtensionData]` parameters, use a `JObject`.  `JObject` implements `IDictionary<string, JToken>`, so it will still work to catch the extra properties.

```
class MusterNode
{
    ...
    [JsonExtensionData]
    private JObject _extparams;
}
```

Then, to populate the other object, you just need to create a reader from the `JObject` and pass it to `JsonSerializer.Populate()` like this:

```
new JsonSerializer().Populate(_extparams.CreateReader(), obj);
```

If you have specific serialization settings you need, you can set them directly on the `JsonSerializer` prior to calling `Populate()`.

Here is a working demo:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/kIzc5G

Comment: works like a snap. Thanks. SerializationSettings can be set like so:                 new JsonSerializer()
                {
                    Converters = { new RGBPixelConverter() },
                    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
                }.Populate(_extparams.CreateReader(), obj);